# How to multiple tabbed interface work in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabbed-interface

I have  web application in that i am using tabbed interface control in this i have create 4 tabs in each tab having a .aspx application,so each application having the
"required field validators" when i click a button in tab2 page it check the validations all the tabbed apllication.How can i solve this problem please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because your tab is submitting your form, causing the javascript to fire on the validators.  A simple fix would be to have the link not submit anything and simply redirect to a new page.

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response, when i redirect the page how to go for second tab .Actually my requirement is all pages will display under tabbed control then only i can easily navigate to another page ...